# Is it possible to display half of the <li>?

Tags: html, css, web

Using `<ul>` + `<li>` :
http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/

Using `<div>` + `<span>` : http://jsfiddle.net/z47LM/

Is it possible to display half of the `<li>`? (like `<div>` + `<span>`)

Comment: Which half? Top, left...? The fiddles don't make it clear what you want at at all.

Comment: @MrLister - think he wants to make the li "wrap" to the next line like it does for the span. See how 12345 is on one line and 67890 is on the other, but that sequence is all part of the same span.

Comment: @jmort253 Oh... I guess I have to start up more browsers then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `float: left;` then it should work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/3/).

as an FYI, you don't need to float left when you `display:inline;`

```
ul{
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:230px;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;a
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:20px;
    display:inline;
    word-break:break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
}​

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li>1234567890</li>
    <li>1234567890</li>
    <li>1234567890</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: +1 Great answer! I added in your code from your jsFiddle. Adding code in the body of your answer makes it stronger -- in case the link ever breaks -- and will help you get more upvotes too! :)

Answer (score 3):

remove `float:left` from the `li` http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li>1234567890</li>
    <li>1234567890</li>
    <li>1234567890</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is your CSS with float:left commented out:

```
ul{
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:230px;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    /*float:left;*/
    border:1px solid red;
    height:20px;
    display:inline;
    word-break:break-all;
}​
```

**note that IE will only wrap the text at whitespace characters.**

Answer (score 2):

Just take out the `float: left` property from `ul li`. However, if you do that you might notice there's a bit of a space between each `li` element. This is because the HTML has some spaces between the `li` tags.

```
<ul>
... <li>A</li>
... <li>B</li>
</ul>
<!-- "..." denotes the spaces I'm talking about -->
```

To remove these spaces, you can either:

- Remove the spaces from the HTML, this will have an impact on the source code readability of course.
- Or, set the `font-size` of the parent (`ul`) to 0. Then, add a `font-size` property to the `li`.
  http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
ul {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:230px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*For IE*/
    *zoom:1;
    white-space:noraml;
    font-size:16px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:20px;
    display:inline;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/1/

Comment: Just FYI, this doesn't appear to "wrap" like in the op's "span" example. Instead, the numbers appear to expand beyond the border but still don't wrap to the next line. Not sure if that's what the op is looking for or if I misunderstood.

Comment: Also FYI, this example sets the display to inline-block and then back to inline, because you forgot to remove the one at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

With following changes it looks like your `div` and `span` example:

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>1234567890</li><li>1234567890</li><li>1234567890</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul{
    border:     1px solid blue;
    width:      210px;
    list-style: none;
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
}
li{
    border:  1px solid red;
    height:  20px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Also see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/FsmcM/4/).